# Only going through first line of input file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def optionFour(self):
 if self == 4:

    inFile = open('dates.csv', 'r')

    for line in inFile:
        gFile = line.strip()
        gFile = gFile.split(',')

        occurence = gFile[0]
        month = int(gFile[1])
        day = int(gFile[2])
        year = int(gFile[3])
        time = gFile[4]
        event = gFile[5]
        dates = [month, day, year]


        day5 = int(input('Enter a day:'))
        month5 = int(input('Enter a month:'))
        year5 = int(input('Enter a year:'))
        dateSelected = [month5, day5, year5]
        if dates == dateSelected:
            return str((occurence, ' appointment starting on (', dateSelected, '): ', time, ', ', event))
        else:
            return str('Nothing')
            break

    inFile.close()
```

It is only going through the first line of the input file why could it be doing that?  It is only checking the first line and nothing else.

Comment: `return` makes the function ...`return`, are you should you don't want to use `continue`?

Comment: Yes, it is as Pedro Lobito says. I won't down vote this question, but please remove it. And please check your code flow before asking questions.

Comment: on first iteration your function comes to `return`. After `return` you will exit function

Comment: Using continue did not work.  It still only went through the first line of the input file.

Comment: "Did not work" is not a problem specification.  Update your posting.

Comment: You can also try setting a boolean initially to False, and use that as the indicator of if you found something. You can place the return statement outside the loop then (after it) and test with the bool you set.

Comment: @MLavrentyev rather than using a boolean flag, you should use the more concise [`else` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) on the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads only one line because that's what you told it to do: read a line, get a date from the user, and compare the two.  If they match, return an appointment; if they don't match, return "Nothing".

Note that you cannot get to either the **break** statement or the file closure: your **returns** force the flow out of the function before you get there.

I suspect that what you need is to read *all* of the lines, store the information, and *then* ask the user for a date to find in that storage.